# ¿Cómo obtener solo el índice que no tiene duplicidad?

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de obtener el índice único dentro de un arreglo en donde hay datos repetidos.

```
[703772, 689465, 689427, 690072, 690072, 689427]
```

Lo que busco es generar un nuevo array pero únicamente con los índices que no tienen duplicidad, por ejemplo tomando el array anterior busco una salida así:

```
[703772, 689465]
```

Lo intente con el método `filter()` pero obtengo lo contrario, me filtra pero me trae los elementos que se duplicaron:

```
ArrIds.filter((item, index) => {
        if (ArrIds.indexOf(item) !== index) {
            arraysDuplicadosDos.push(item);
        }
    });
```

¿Hay alguna forma u otro método que pudiera usar para realizar lo que busco? de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede hacerse en dos pasos, primero contar las repeticiones de cada número y luego filtrar el arreglo:

```js
let arreglo = [703772, 689465, 689427, 690072, 690072, 689427]
let contador = {}
// guardar contadores para cada número del arreglo
// si no se ha creado el contador se crea con valor 1
// si ya exite se incrementa su valor
arreglo.forEach(n => { contador[n] ? contador[n]++ : contador[n] = 1 })
// se usaba el objeto de los contadores para filtrar el arreglo
let unicos = arreglo.filter(n => contador[n] == 1)
console.log(unicos)
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho amigo, es justo lo que buscaba :)

Answer (score 1):

puede funcionar de esta manera, solo aplico un filtro sobre otro, uno para tener los numeros que no se repiten y el otro para validar si hay numeros repetidos, el segundo filtro lo que realmente hace es tomar todos los números iguales al parametro e y los filtra en un arreglo, si el mi variable `repetidos` es igual a 1 entonces no hay mas numeros repetidos en su arreglo

```js
const arreglos = [703772, 689465, 689427, 690072, 690072, 689427];

const filtrado = arreglos.filter(e => {
  const repetidos = arreglos.filter(i => i == e);
  return repetidos.length == 1;
})

console.log(filtrado)
```

Comment: Acortando más tu código: podrías directamente escribir `return repetidos.length == 1;`.

Comment: Totalmente cierto, al final solo filtrará cuando esa condición sea verdadera, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El enfoque que tenías no estaba mal orientado, solo faltaría utilizar `.splice` si está presente, es decir quitar el elemento o agregarlo si no está previamente (`.push`), al completar una iteración van a quedar los elementos que solo están una vez.

```js
const arr = [703772, 689465, 689427, 690072, 690072, 689427];

const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => { // <-- Se itera una sola vez

  let idx = p.indexOf(c); // <-- Se itera solo los únicos de este momento

  (idx > -1) ? p.splice(idx, 1): p.push(c);

  return p; 

}, []);


console.log(res);
```

Y es óptimo porque la segunda iteración es solo del grupo de únicos de ese momento, es decir en el peor de los casos (todos distíntos) se realizaría una iteración completa (dentro de la principal) solo en el último elemento.

Answer (score 0):

este me sirvió a mi

let array1 = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3]

let [num]=array1.filter((v)=>array1.indexOf(v)===array1.lastIndexOf(v));

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]